# Mandrill - Rules overriding with blank html content

Tags: mandrill, rule-engine

I am very new to Mandrill and whilst trying to use the Rules Engine (via SMTP integration without using Headers, with the incoming email being text), I have configured an open rule that states:

```
if
sender's email matches scott***@****.com
then
set template to TestTemplate using template block body
```

but instead of the incoming message being inserted into the body block, as per the following html that's in the TestTemplate

```
<div mc:edit="header">
     <h2>Testing Testing</h2>
</div>
<div mc:edit="**body**" style="color:#000000;">
      <h2>123 123</h2>
</div>
<div mc:edit="footer">
     Company contact information will go here.
</div>
```

The 123 123 is being overwritten with blank content i.e. not what's being passed in on the original email message

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you supply the original message (API call + HTML and/or text content, or SMTP message) that you're initially sending over to Mandrill? (API keys/identifying info can be redacted). The `<h2>123 123</h2>` should be replaced by something - that's the default content for that block - but what it's replaced with is going to depend on the message you're sending over (ie, what it looks like before the Rule gets applied).

Comment: This is the text of the email coming from the application Dear Adv Test.

Your invoice INV00000117 is available:

Invoice Due Date: 01/10/2015
Invoice Total Amount: 16.50 AUD

Great to be here!

Thank you for your business! I've tried to get the outbound request but have not had any luck thus far. Also just to add that the email also includes an attachment which in fact is being passed through Mandrill successfully it's the text that's missing

Comment: Hi Kaitlin 
I'm trying to attach an extract of the SMTP message example that gets sent across but the comment window won't allow the number of characters, is there another way to get this across to you?
Thanks